# Make a color changeable image for html?

Tags: html, css, png, photoshop

So I'd like to know the best way to make a PNG image color-changeable. 
I have it on Photoshop and it's supposed to be on lots of different colors on my site, and I don't want to go through the hassle of saving it in all of them.

Is there an easier way to do that? Like creating a font? Saving it as a format that html can change the color?

Thanks in advance

Comment: color of image or color of background

Comment: The image has a transparent background, I want to change the color of the actual "shape" that is my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your PNG to SVG (there are online converters available like this one http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg) and then manage it's color with a 'stroke' and 'fill' properties. It's impossible to change color of a binary file (which a PNG file is) using CSS. If this option is not acceptable then make a sprite (https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Comment: I saved it as an SVG and started searching for how to use these properties. Now this is the problem, there are many ways to embed svgs, many ways to style them, some have support to fill, some don't, and I don't know which sites to trust. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CSS filter property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

I think the one you want is `hue-rotate()`.

And here it is for IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858632(v=vs.85).aspx

Example:

```
/* CSS */

img {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```